# PHP array from Ajax : SQL request format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax, pdo

I am a bit lost with my PHP file. 
I want to find an array with all my datas in the database, and send it with ajax to my js file (this part is OK).

Now, i have :

```
$cnx = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=simul','root','');
$cnx->query('SET NAMES utf8');
$cnx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$req = $cnx->prepare('Select * from price');
$req-> execute();

$data = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
print_r($data);
```

My JS :

```
function set_global_var(){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: '/global.php',
        async: false,
        success: function(rep){console.log(rep);},
    }); 
}
```

Print_r :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [small-bronze] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [small-silver] => 10
    )
)
```

And to access it fast, I just want something like :

```
[small-bronze] => 5
[small-silver] => 10
[small-gold] => 15
```

Data Base :

```
item            price
small-bronze    5
```

How can I do this efficiently ? Is PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR wrong ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: looks strange. I'd bet on your own post processing.  can you provide  a real life code snippet that actually works instead of an artificial made up sketch? BTW, how many fields in the table?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I agree, first time seeing this. Now edited, enough informations ?

Comment: Well, all I could suggest is to create an [MCVE that everyone could run and confirm your case](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve).

Comment: given the ouptut provided, most likely you are running another version of code where PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is actually used instead of PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR

Comment: Yeah... That's it... There was an old version in local.. I feel a bit stupid, but thanks, now it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

global.php

```
$cnx = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=simul','root','');
$cnx->query('SET NAMES utf8');
$cnx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$req = $cnx->prepare('Select * from price');
$req-> execute();

$data = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
echo json_encode($data);
```

MY JS

```
function set_global_var(){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: '/global.php',
        async: false, // this is not required (in this case)
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(rep){
           console.log(rep);

           //You can access each items of JSON array as below.
           $.each(resp, function(i, val) {
              console.log(val.small-bronze);
           }

        },
    }); 
 }
```

Following links would be helpful to you to learn more about this.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Perfect, cleaner with the json datatype + PHP json encode, thx for the tip

Answer (score -1):

I replaced :

```
$req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

With :

```
$array = array();
while($row = $req->fetch()) {
    $array[$row['item']] = $row['prix'];
}
```

Now I have :

```
[small-bronze] => 5
[small-silver] => 10
[small-gold] => 15
```

Do the job, a bit disappointed that FETCH_KEY_PAIR doesn't work in my case ..

Comment: No no, It was a mistake and my fault. Just I replaced FETCH_KEY_PAIR with a while, which do the job better. I worked on my code this weekend, and I was thinking that post my actual code could help someone, so I post it. Sorry to try to do things the right way..